# Shape transformation using Quartz (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-manipulation, quartz-graphics

I have to program a drawing tool that should display shapes on a plane. These shapes could either be arbitrary shapes, like an elipse or a cube, or some picture that would be drawn on the plane.

What I need to do is, using marker points positioned all around these shapes, be able to transform them by moving the markers. So for instance assuming I have four markers positioned at the top, bottom, left and right, I should be able to stretch the shape horizontally by moving the left and right markers.

I can't use  geometric properties of the shape (like changing the radius of the ellipse for instance) since I have to be able to do that on arbitrary shapes (like pictures).

I don't have much experience in image manipulation algorithms, can any one give me some hints of where to start ? Eventually best practice to do it good or even a good algorithm to do that ?

I am developing for the iOS platform.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the [Quartz 2D Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html) in the [Apple Developer Center](http://developer.apple.com)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you draw onto a UIImage

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(width, height)); 
// do your drawing operations
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); 
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Here's how you can scale that image

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(scaledWidth, scaledHeight)); 
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0, scaledWidth, scaledHeight)];
UIImage *scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); 
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

You don't have to do it in two steps -- you could just draw each item scaled.  That would be better for the non image drawing.

If you need a CGContextRef to draw, you can use this

```
CGContextRef context = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];
```